# Animated film about a group of people from a television show

Tags: animation, story-identification, movie

This film has been stuck in my mind for such a long time. I have checked every Wikipedia entry on cross-dimension films, time travel films, and teleportation films, but I cannot find it. I hope one of you can help me!

This film is a 3D animation. I can remember the film starting and the camera panning into a living room, with some narration over the top. The camera then goes into the TV to show this universe which is the TV show. I remember that a handful of the characters get taken from that universe and get taken to Earth. There's a lot of travelling to try and get home - there's a café scene, a toy store scene, and an fight scene right at the end. There is this scientist antagonist that is behind the cross-dimension transportation. The film ends with the characters foiling his plans, making popcorn come out of all the screens (including the screen of the living room in the opening scene), and then all the characters get home.

It's definitely in English. The target audience is children.

Most probably made in the US. It was made more than 8 years ago.

I can't remember character names otherwise I would have probably found it by now. The main character is a male character. He has some interactions a with female character. The male character, if I remember correctly, had some sort of grappling hook gun. All the detail I know about this film is in the description above. I cannot remember anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was also just looking for this film, I loved it as a kid. Finally found the name and it was called [Boo, Zino and the Snurks](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0395947/)!!

> The beautiful world of Gaya is home to a community of creatures, who
>   are much smaller than humans, but who have an uncanny resemblance to
>   them. But the Gayans are facing imminent danger. Someone has stolen
>   the magic stone called Dalamite without which this world is doomed.
>   Two Gayans named Boo and Zino embark on a dangerous mission to track
>   down and recover the stone. As they attempt to find the stone, their
>   journey takes them into another world that is both strange and
>   frightening!

Answer (score 1):

In the US it's actually titled just "The Snurks". It's dumb and I hate it. It's "Back to Gaya" in its country of origin. I refuse to call it anything else.

Also, it was Germany's first feature length CGI film, made by a small team of people who basically expanded on a final school project. Just to kinda excuse the awkwardness and obscurity of it, I guess. I love it though. It will always have a special place in my heart.

[edit] Oh, sorry. It's a pretty obscure film, so it's hard to find accurate information about it online, let alone a well-written synopsis. If you look at the IMDB article, it's under the title Boo, Zino & The Snurks, but the image is of the US release, The Snurks. There is also an article for it on TV Tropes.

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0395947/
http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WesternAnimation/BooZinoAndTheSnurks

And here's my own synopsis:

The brave but dense Zino (Glenn Wrage), and his intelligent but shy partner, Boo (Alan Marriott), live in the beautiful world of Gaya, where Zino's fame has gotten the attention of the Snurks, three cheaters who would do anything to take the spotlight from him. After a great race, the sky darkens and opens, sucking up a magical stone from its pedestal in the town square, the Dalamite. The Snurks, hoping to be seen as heroes, make for the Dalamite, only to be sucked up into the vortex. Zino is quick to follow, pulling his buddy with him. Alanta (Emily Watson), the mayor's daughter who is desperate for adventure and tired of being an ornament, breaks away from the guards to also make for the vortex, leaving Gaya in chaos. Without the Dalamite, Gaya is doomed to crumble.

On the other side of the vortex, the characters find themselves in a dark world of giants. Here, it becomes apparent that their lives are entirely fictional, a fantasy world created by an old man named Albert Drollinger (Patrick Stewart) which has become a popular television series. The Gayans are hunted down by another TV star, a mad scientist called Professor N. Icely, who has developed a machine with the ability to bring things from the world of television into the physical realm. But it needs a stronger, more reliable power source in order to carry out his revenge.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Can you include a link, a synopsis, and/or details as to why this fits the question.